# Kubernetes : Service Accounts Permissions issue with Spring Cloud Data Flow Server

Tags: spring, kubernetes, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have been trying to setup Spring Cloud Dataflow Server for Kubernetes locally using minikube. Have followed the installation instructions in the the link here : [SCDF Installation Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-kubernetes/docs/1.4.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#_installation)

I've been getting the below error for the SCDF server:

```
11:32:52.095 [main] DEBUG io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.Config - Trying to configure client namespace from Kubernetes service account namespace path...
11:32:52.096 [main] DEBUG io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.Config - Found service account namespace at: [/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/namespace].
2018-04-24 11:33:14.348  WARN 1 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.kubernetes.StandardPodUtils    : Failed to get pod with name:[scdf-server-869d56967c-97lsd]. You should look into this if things aren't working as you expect. Are you missing serviceaccount permissions?

io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Failure executing: GET at: https://kubernetes.default.svc/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/scdf-server-869d56967c-97lsd. Message: Forbidden!Configured service account doesn't have access. Service account may have been revoked. pods "scdf-server-869d56967c-97lsd" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:default" cannot get pods in the namespace "default".
```

Below are the version details:

- Spring Cloud Data Flow Server : 1.4.0.RELEASE
- Kubernetes Local Deployment using minikube
- Kubernetes Version : 1.10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The latest release of minikube enabled RBAC by default.

For RBAC enabled clusters, we have added a note in the installation section on this matter.

*"The latest releases of kubernetes have enabled RBAC on the api-server. If your target platform has RBAC enabled you must ask a cluster-admin to create the roles and role-bindings for you before deploying the dataflow server. They associate the dataflow service account with the roles it needs to be run with."*

For minikube, however, you can run the following command and retry installaing.

> kubectl create clusterrolebinding add-on-cluster-admin --clusterrole=cluster-admin --serviceaccount=kube-system:default

Alternatively, if you're using the helm-chart, you can disable RBAC and install the chart with the following on minikube.

> helm init
>
> helm repo add incubator https://kubernetes-charts-incubator.storage.googleapis.com
>
> helm repo update
>
> helm install --name my-release --set server.service.type=NodePort --set rbac.create=false incubator/spring-cloud-data-flow

Comment: Have tried this approach too, exactly the same error as shared earlier.

Comment: I just tried the RBAC provisioning experience on minikube `v0.26.1`. I created the `cluster-admin` role and I used the helm chat (via: `helm install --name my-release  --set server.service.type=NodePort 
 incubator/spring-cloud-data-flow`). Everything came up as expected.

Comment: I tried the helm way of installation earlier, but without the cluster-admin role. Just tried these together as you've mentioned above, and it worked both locally and on Google Kubernetes engine.
Thank you so much. Also, wondering if this should be part of the SCDF reference docs. Kindly suggest.

Comment: Yes, that'd be good to have it in the docs. I added [spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-kubernetes#282](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-kubernetes/issues/282).

Answer (score 0):

From the installation guide, step 7: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-kubernetes/docs/1.4.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#_deploying_using_kubectl

> The latest releases of kubernetes have enabled RBAC on the api-server. If your target platform has RBAC enabled you must ask a cluster-admin to create the roles and role-bindings for you before deploying the dataflow server. They associate the dataflow service account with the roles it needs to be run with.

```
$ kubectl create -f src/kubernetes/server/server-roles.yaml
$ kubectl create -f src/kubernetes/server/server-rolebinding.yaml
```

Did you perform those steps?

Comment: Yes, I had applied these too.

Comment: It looks like https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-kubernetes/blob/master/src/kubernetes/server/server-rolebinding.yaml grants permissions to the `scdf-sa` service account, not the `default` service account. Did you create the deployment from https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-kubernetes/blob/master/src/kubernetes/server/server-deployment.yaml (which includes `serviceAccountName: scdf-sa`)

Comment: I got this resolved following Sabby Anandans answer. Thanks for the help.